# match.call() returns ..1 when evaluated in a sub function

Tags: r

I have two functions

```r
fn1 <- function(...) {
  fn2(...)
}
```

I have a second function

```r
fn2 <- function(...) {
  match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
}
```

Calling the first function with a symbol does not return the expected value

```r
fn1(test)
# [[1]]
# ..1
```

I would expect `test` to be returned (a `symbol`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `substitute`

```
fn2 <- function(...) {
     eval(substitute(alist(...) ))

   }
fn2(test)
#[[1]]
#test
fn1(test)
#[[1]]
#test
```